# Office 2003 PIAs with Office 2007

Tags: office-2003, pia

Is it possible to target Outlook 2003 in a vb.net 2008 Windows application when working on a system that only has Office 2007 installed on it? I downloaded the 2003 PIAs, but they wont install without Office 2003 installed first. The point is, I don't want Office 2003 installed on my development machine.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you have to browse to the PIAs directly when adding the reference.